# Programmatically removing/adding constraints animated

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I'm having difficulties removing and adding constraints programmatically with animation. I've simplified my existing project into a small project just for demonstration.

Setup is there are two (container) views: top and bottom. They contain two subviews: blue and red.

Top view has aspect ratio 2:3 constraint.

[image: View hierarchy]
[image: View hierarchy]

I have reference to topView, aspectRatioConstraint and heightConstraint which I initialize in viewDidLoad

```
  @IBOutlet weak var aspectRatioConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  @IBOutlet weak var topView: UIView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: topView.frame.size.height)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([heightConstraint])
    topView.removeConstraint(aspectRatioConstraint)
  }

  @IBAction func startAnimation(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
      self.heightConstraint.constant = 20.0
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      }, completion: nil)
  }
```

"+" button in navigation calls startAnimation method and it should resize heightConstraint over period of time, but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Sample project -> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7i75i0zq9dormqb/AACzTYvWOoJL3MjcjgMIyOd9a?dl=0

Comment: What is the problem? The resize does not animate or it does not resize at all?

Comment: How you are able to activate constraint in viewDidLoad? It's supposed to crash, because the constraint are not ready at that time.

Comment: @MaksTheAwesome doesn't resize at all.

Dasem I've figured that one out. I've implemented in viewDidLayoutSubviews() if heightConstraint is nil { init heightConst, activate it, remove aspectRatioConst }

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
      NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.heightConstraint])
      self.heightConstraint.constant = 20.0
      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.heightConstraint])
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }, completion: nil)
```

You have deactivate before updating some constraints

Comment: And have you tried to also :

`topView.layoutIfNeeded()` instead of self.view ?

Comment: the last thing I see, that you can try is to update all the constraint not just the constant.

`self.heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)`

Comment: I download your project and apparently there is an error in your constraints.

Start by fixing that :)

Comment: Because it's non-sense to add the frame.height of a view as a constant height constraint. You're using constraints to avoid using static frame.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/125718/coding-auto-layout

Comment: It's not non-sense. Aspect ratio constraint will resize view depending on screen width, i.e. for iPhone 6 it will be 375:250. Now knowing the height of the frame, plan is to switch constraints, because aspect is not needed anymore. What I want to change is height after some action.

Comment: I don't really get your point. 

but anyway you have a constraint error on the top view height. So if you want to be able to animate it, you first have to resolve it :)

Answer (score 1):

I was confused by your project because of the subviews within subviews, but I created a project of my own that should do what you need. Two side notes about your project first:

(1) The AutoLayout error you were getting was when changing the constraints in code. I don't know why it was happening... maybe because you were nesting full-sized subviews within each other, or something else.

(2) I would hesitate on altering/creating constraints in ViewDidLoad() where possible. UIView really doesn't have what it needs. I try to do my constraint changes in ViewWillLayoutSubviews() instead.

Here's what I did, basically a subset of your project:

**(1)** Setup what you can in IB. Two views in the Storyboard (no nested subviews, though I think it should work). Of course, also wire up your navigation controller's add button!

**(2)** Add the following constraints:

Top View:

-- Leading, Trailing, and Top margins are 0
-- Aspect Ratio is 3:2
-- Height is 20

Bottom View:

-- All margins set to 0

**(3) Correct the IB "error" by setting the priority on the Top View's height from "required" to "high".**

**(4) Add IBOutlets for both the aspect and height constraints to the view controller.**

(5) The following code (which was close in your project) is all you need in your view controller. Note that I added **no** code whatsoever anywhere else:

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightRatio: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var aspectRatio: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func animateLayoutChange(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.aspectRatio.isActive = false
        self.heightRatio.isActive = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@IBAction func startAnimation(_ sender: AnyObject) {
self.heightConstraint.constant = 20.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      }, completion: nil)
  }
```

Comment: Tried this earlier and it didn't help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to animate height of topView you can try this :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.topView.frame.size.height = 20.0
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: That's the problem (good thing) with constraints. If you try to change view's frame, constraint won't let that happen, that is they'll force view back in place

Comment: In the example app your goal is to make topView height = 20, and also keep the top constraint of bottomView pinned to bottom edge of topView, right?

Comment: Exactly. Changing height constraint to 20 should let bottom view expand